# The age of the Earth and evolution of life?

Tags: time, evolution

Assuming dinosaurs actually did exist and did so millions of years before humans...

How does the the teachings of Islam explain the time that has passed and all of the other life forms that came and went extinct long before modern human life existed at all?

It is known that 90-95% of all life that ever existed on this Earth was already extinct long before the great flood mentioned in holy texts. How does Islam address the pre-modern Primates, we are Primates too, that were here long before us?

Comment: Islam is not against the documented history and science in general. If you bring a proof on the exact age of the Earth, then Islam will accept it as such.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing. Islam does not mention anything that happens before Prophet Adam PBUH. What happened before is irrelevant religiously and if scientific evidence proves that earth has been here for 4.543 billion years there is no reason for us to not agree with that assessment. We don't know who and what lived during that time, besides bacteria which we have documented, no one knows what was living during that time. Dinosaurs did exist as science proves but I assume that it did before the times of Human beings (again as science proves).

Evolution is a totally different disputable subject. In Islam we believe that humans were created by God starting with Adam, not evolved out of Apes etc.. Animals on the other hand could've evolved as a special feature by Allah. That deserves a topic on its own I think.